# TCPDFで日本語テキストと画像を出力する場合の文字化けについて

Tags: php, pdf, xampp

Unityで作成したWindows PCアプリから、PDF生成を行うPHPスクリプトに対して日本語テキストと100KB未満の画像（バイナリデータ）をpostし、PDF出力を行っています。

日本語テキストのみpostした場合は、文字化けなく正常に出力されます。
日本語テキストと画像1点をpostした場合は、画像は正常に出力されますが、日本語テキストの文字化けが発生します。
PHPスクリプトの画像出力箇所をコメントアウトして、日本語テキストと画像1点をpostした場合も、日本語テキストの文字化けが発生します。

メモリ不足が問題ではないかと思い、ini_set関数やphp.iniなどでmemory_limitを128M、256M、512Mと変えてみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

もし、上記の現象や原因に関する情報やヒントがございましたら、ご教示よろしくお願い致します。
環境は次のとおりです。

Windows 10 Pro 64bit
XAMPP 5.6.15 (PHP 5.6.15)
TCPDF 6.2.12
Unity 5.2.3f1
※Windows PCアプリとXAMPP環境は同一PC内に共存

送信側サンプルコード

```
private IEnumerator PostWithBinary2(byte[] byteData, System.Action<WWW> callback)
{
    string url = "http://localhost/report/sample.php";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("title", "日本語タイトル");
    form.AddField("date", "2016-01-01");
    form.AddField("copyright", "Copyright (C) 2016 日本語著作者. All Rights Reserved");
    form.AddBinaryData("picture", byteData, "picture.png", "image/png");

    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
    yield return www;

    if (callback != null)
    {
        callback(www);
    }
}
```

受信側サンプルコード

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    private $hTitle='';
    private $hDate='';
    private $fCopyright='';

    //Constructor
    function __construct($orientation,$unit,$format,$unicode,$encoding,$diskcache,$pdfa,$title,$date,$copyright)
    {
        parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$format,$unicode,$encoding,$diskcache,$pdfa);
        $this->hTitle=$title;
        $this->hDate=$date;
        $this->fCopyright=$copyright;
    }

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $imageFile=dirname(__FILE__).'/logo.jpg';
        if(file_exists($imageFile))
        {
            $this->Image($imageFile,10,15,32,0,'JPG','','T',false,150,'',false,false,0,false,false,false);
        }
        // Title
        $this->SetXY(50,22.5);
        $this->SetFont('cid0jp','B',16);
        $this->Cell(110,20,$this->hTitle,0,false,'C',0,'',0,false,'L','M');
        // Date
        $this->SetX(190);
        $this->SetFont('cid0jp','',14);
        $this->Cell(0,20,$this->hDate,0,false,'R',0,'',0,false,'L','M');
     }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Copyright
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('cid0jp','',10);
        $this->Cell(0,10,$this->fCopyright,0,false,'C',0,'',0,false,'T','M');
    }
}

// check Image
function checkImage($file)
{
    if($file['type']!='image/png')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if($file['error']>0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],dirname(__FILE__).'/images/'.$file['name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf=new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION,PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,true,'UTF-8',false,false,$_POST['title'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['copyright']);
$pdf->setHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO,PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH,PDF_HEADER_TITLE,PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('cid0jp','',14));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('cid0jp','',14);
$pdf->SetFillColor(230);

// output Image
if(array_key_exists('picture',$_FILES))
{
    $file=$_FILES['picture'];
    if (checkImage($file))
    {
        $x=10;
        $y=125;
        $pdf->Image(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/'.$file['name'],$x,$y,92,0,'PNG','','',true,200,'',false,false,1,false,false,false);
    }
}

// save PDF
$reportFile=dirname(__FILE__).'/report.pdf';
if(file_exists($reportFile))
{
    unlink($reportFile);
}
$pdf->Output($reportFile,'F');

// return JSON
$json = array(
    'resultReportFile'=>(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'http://':'https://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/report.pdf'),
    'error'=>'',
);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

文字化けしなかった例
[image: ヘッダー部とフッター部に日本語テキスト出力。左上の青い箇所はPHPスクリプトと同じ場所にある画像を出力。]

文字化けした例
[image: ヘッダー部とフッター部に日本語テキスト出力。中央の画像がpostしたもの。]

Comment: 送信側受信側両方のコードと、出力例(文字化けの状況)を追記してください

Comment: ありがとうございます。送受信サンプルコードと出力例を追記しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決です。

multipart/form-dataでファイルをアップすると文字化けするという情報が、随分前のものでしたがありました。
[マルチパートフォームの挙動に注意する](http://randd.kwappa.net/2008/08/16/34)

そこでひとまず、php.iniを次のように変更しました。

変更前: `mbstring.http_input = auto`
変更後: `mbstring.http_input = UTF-8`

こちらを参考にしました。
[mbstring.encoding_translationが原因で文字化け](http://nob-log.info/2013/03/25/mbstring-encoding_translation/)